# What is the role of aging counter and debounce counter in AUTOSAR while logging DTC?

Tags: autosar

I am new to AUTOSAR and i am trying to understand how a DTC is logged but i am confused with aging and debounce counter. Please help me to understand how DTC is logged ?

Comment: What happens if the fault condition is not present, aging counter is decreasing and once the fault condition is present again, the question is: the aging counter will be set back to default or should remain where it left off

Comment: The aging counter is only decreased, if the event did not happen in the last operation cycle. As soon as there is a new Occurence of the event, the aging counter is reset.

Answer (score 6):

The Dem module offers two (among many others) important services to log the status of DTC. One "Dem_SetEventStatus" is used by SwC and another "Dem_ReportErrorStatus" is used by BSW components. Whenever a DTC fault conditions is detected i.e. non-reception of a CAN messages, depending upon the components, DTC logging request is send to DEM module by corresponding services.

**Debouncing Counter** In order to avoid unintentional jitters in fault conditions, debouncing may be introduced in either reporter module or in DEM module. Debouncing counter in DEM module simply counts for debounce period for the configured event before saving the DTC in memory.

**Aging Counter** The Dem module provides the ability to remove a specific event from the event memory,
if its fault conditions are not fulfilled for a certain period of time (operation cycles).
This process is called as "aging" or "unlearning".